# whenever a object is outputed all it says is <character_template.characer object at 0x0398DA50>

Tags: python

I'm making a text-based adventure game and having a bit of a problem with the enemies since whenever one of them comes out all it says is

```
class characer:
    def __init__(self,name,health,items):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.items = items

def make_NPC():
    global npc
    health = [64,75,32,93,12,54]
    enemy_list = ["bandit","junkie","mutated human"]
    items = ["weapon","food","health items"]
    npc_name = random.choice(enemy_list)
    npc_health = random.choice(health)
    npc_items = random.choice(items)
    npc = characer(npc_name,npc_health,npc_items,)

def state_combat():
    make_NPC()
    global state
    print(npc)
    attack = 12
    while state == "combat":
        fight = input("press F to fight")
        if fight == "F":
            npc.health =- attack
            print(npc)
        elif fight == "I":
            print("items coming soon")
        elif fight == "E":
            print("you've escaped the battle")
            state = "defult"
        elif npc.health == 0:
            print("you won")
            state = "defult"
```

Comment: What is `characer` and how do you print it?

Comment: You can define a `__str__` or `__repr__` method to get a nice representation of your objects; see https://dbader.org/blog/python-repr-vs-str